# How to spy on a transaction that is not yet committed in Postgres for debugging?

Tags: postgresql, transactions

Is there a postgres tool that would allow me to spy on a transaction and run queries as if as I was part of  that transaction.

I have a break point on my java code which has started a transaction but has not yet committed the transaction because it is waiting at a break point. What I would like to do is to able to see the state of the database the way that the transaction sees it.

Ideally I would like a tool that would let me have a sql console of some kind where I can type stuff as part of that tx, so I could write select statements to see things that have not yet been committed.

I only need such a tool for my development workstation, I am using postgres 9.1 but can easily upgrade to 9.2 or 9.3 if needed.

Comment: See if the issue occurs in 9.2 or 9.3. Potentially, see if it occurs with either in serializable isolation.

Comment: @Denis it is not a concurrency issue that I am tracing down, rather it is a problem with Hibernate not properly cascading EntityManager.remove() calls and basically not being able to read by an association it just inserted all of this within the same tx.

Comment: It could be a concurrency issue imho, and since Postgres improves and fixes bugs from a version to the next, I'd still advise to try it after upgrading. Moreover, the issue might simply be a lock that is being waited for or such; if it is, trying to switch to serializable isolation (9.2 or higher) might fix the problem all by itself -- at least you'd have a good lead as to why it's occurring in the first place.

Comment: A low level hack might be the [pageinspec](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pageinspect.html) module. You would need to find the page where the row in question is located though and I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: `SELECT * FROM heap_page_items(get_raw_page('table', 0));` will only return system columns, though.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not aware of any out of the box means to "view" or replay what is going on exactly, but there are a few hidden columns, functions and catalogs that may be of help in your forensics.

The key [system columns](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-system-columns.html) of interest to you are xmin and xmax. You can query them like so:

```
SELECT xmin, xmax, ... FROM table
```

As an aside, be wary that their type is `xid`. That's a very capricious version of integer that only responds to `=` as an operator. Also, it can only be cast to text and back:

```
select 1::text::xid::text::int, not(1::text::xid = 2::text::xid);
```

From outside of the offending transaction, `xmax` would hold the offending transaction's id if the row was updated or deleted by the latter. <del>I'm unaware of any way to see newly inserted rows.</del>

To peek at new rows (though with very little useful information), you can use the [pageinspect](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pageinspect.html) contrib:

```
SELECT * FROM heap_page_items(get_raw_page('table', 0));
```

There are some potentially interesting [system information functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-TXID-SNAPSHOT) to understand what the latter do. They return and make use of a `txid_snapshot` (an equally capricious type) for use with those columns. I'm afraid I'm unaware of any means to get the precise `xip_list` of an in-progress transaction without being within it, let alone to masquerade as it when running `select` statements to view the database as it does, however.

Lastly, there are a view and a table of interest:

```
select * from pg_stat_activity;
select * from pg_locks;
```

The first, [pg_stat_activity](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html), will give you the last query for your transaction, along with its `pid`.

That second, [pg_locks](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-locks.html), will give you the offending `xid` given a `pid`, along with the various locks that it acquired on other tables and table rows, so you know where to begin to look.

You could then check out what got touched by running queries such as:

```
select * from table where xmax = 123::text::xid;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could likely hack something together using pgbouncer. Pgbouncer is a connection pooler which connects to the db directly on your behalf. What I'd do is to lower the pgbouncer connection limit to, say 1 connection.. then, run your app to the point of your failure and somehow disconnect from the db. The connection will still be open between the db and pgbouncer-- you'll have to adjust the "server_reset_query" in pgbouncer to something that won't roll everything back and discard everything. I haven't tested this, but it's the only lead I have, and I think you could get it to work.